# SignalR configuration on IIS 6 / windows server 2003 R2

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I'm getting error 404 when I access signalr/hubs url on a web app deployed on IIS 6 / winSrv 2003 r2.

I've tried runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests = true and false. However I found in one of the #issues a comment that says that this is for II7 and >.

Also I've set the wildcard mapping to v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll and still getting the same error 404.

IIS 6 Log error:

> W3SVC1 127.0.0.1 GET /devweb/signalr/hubs - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+5.2;+Trident/4.0;+.NET+CLR+1.1.4322;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.4506.2152;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) 404 0 3

When I deployed to IIS 7 on Win7 works fine. I need to make it work on IIS 6 as well so it can be deployed to some customers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set the mapping as "All Verbs" ?

Comment: I set .compiled to All verbs without the 'verify ...' checkbox.. and fixed the problem!!!!. THANKS A LOT!!!!

Comment: No problem =).  I worked at smarterasp.net for over 10yrs. I see this kind of problems everyday.

Comment: Can you describe where 'All Verbs' is located and what needs to be changed to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/ranw/2011/01/11/configure-your-aspnet-application-that-uses-routing-in-iis-6/) solution worked for me.

1. Go to Properties of the Asp.Net application in IIS manager
2. Click on Configuration
3. Click on Insert (to insert a wildcard application map)
4. Paste the pathaspnet_isapi.dll: c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll
5. Uncheck: verify that file exists
6. press ok and close all dialogs.