# Two-way communication between web application and desktop application

Tags: .net, ajax, wcf, web, desktop-application

I am curious if this scenario is even possible:

1. .Net Windows Forms application (our product) with a couple of WCF services exposed (self hosted, for example on 'http://localhost:8000/myservice/method1'), running in elevated mode.
2. A web application (from another manufacturer) on a public domain, which would communicate with our application in a two-way mode:

   1. web application to desktop application: during the setup of our application we register a custom protocol 'xxx' (similar to 'mailto') and set our application as a handler for this protocol. So the web application can trigger an action in our desktop application with links in the form 'href="xxx:parameters"'.
   2. desktop application to web application: the web application would periodically (every second for example) poll our **localhost** WCF services via javascript ajax calls.

Is the 2.2 option even possible? Which binding should we use for WCF services? Are there any problems with cross domain calls (from public domain to localhost)?

Edit - yes, the communication is not two-way because in our scenario the desktop application cannot directly manipulate the web application. The polling option is just an idea how to get state from desktop application to web application, so if there are better alternatives I would very much like to hear about it :)

There are a couple of other alternatives for communication between web application and desktop application (java plugins, active x for IE, firefox plugins, chrome native plugin,...) but they are very fragile regarding new versions of browsers, versions of java, version of Windows,... and you have to maintain all of them. We are looking for a option which would work on all major browsers and that the manufacturer, which is responsible for web application, would have as little work as possible.

Comment: Is the web application from another manufacturer hosted on a server you can control?

Comment: @mageos - no, and we would like to design the system so that the other manufacturer would have as little additional work as possible.

Comment: What is the communication with the other manufacturer?  Is it a restful API? SOAP based? Is there a know API that both sides are using?

Comment: @mageos - it is a 'regular' asp.net web page, hosted in IIS. No public API or other fancy stuff. I also added an edit, hope it is a bit clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the 2.2 option even possible?

[Yes](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128478/Consuming-WCF-REST-Services-Using-jQuery-AJAX-Call)

> Which binding should we use for WCF services?

1. For the incoming calls from the web app (href links) you should expose your service operation as a REST endpoint, using WCF [webHttpBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412176%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or something like [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/), which is much lighter.
2. For the polling, as already mentioned, you need to host another REST endpoint.

> Two-way communication between web application and desktop application

Based on your description, this doesn't appear to be a genuine two-way requirement, as in duplex (calls going both ways). In both scenarios you outline the calls originate on the partner website. It's only the responses which travel the other way, or am I missing something?

> The polling option is just an idea how to get state from desktop
>   application to web application

Strictly speaking, the polling originator is not the web app *per se*, but the client browser via JavaScript. Apart from any architectural concerns of using a client app as an intermediary between desktop and server, there is a very real complication around implementing [cross-origin scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) in the browser.

I suggest a better solution would be to call the web app from the desktop app when state changes, and then have the web app "notify" the web client, either via ajax polling (to the web app), or [something like SignalR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471780/asp-net-http-server-push-to-client).

This would likely be not much more work for your partner as although they would need to host a new "Status Changed" endpoint for you to call, the ajax polling task would probably be simpler seeing as they'd be polling their own service rather than yours.

Comment: We don't use WCF for option 2.1 (web app -> desktop app) but a custom protocol 'xxx' (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/07/14/url-protocols-application-protocols-and-asynchronous-pluggable-protocols-oh-my.aspx). This works nicely.

Comment: Yes, this is not a genuine two-way communication because we don't send information from desktop app to web app; the web app should poll our desktop application for new information. I added an edit to my question.

Comment: as far as I know SignalR works only Windows Server 2008 or newer but the web application works on Windows Server 2003. And even if it would work then the manufacturer would have to create a couple of web services so that our desktop application would call them and the web server would then update the browser, right?

Comment: @sventevit - yes that would be my suggestion. Regarding SignalR IIS version see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179103/signalr-configuration-on-iis-6-windows-server-2003-r2